# Hyperref isn't working right with lineno

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, links, lineno

For my end-of-year stats notes, I cite everything in line numbers because it makes everything much more specific, and it's relevant to my needs. I tried adding in hyperlinks so that it would be easier to move around the pdf, as it's gotten quite sizeable, but the `hyperref` package has started to put out the following warning:

```
Suppressing link with empty target on input line [line number].
```

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening. (I will note that I've been using commands `\fromline` to label lines and `\toline` to reference them in order to increase efficiency, but I don't see why that would be a problem.)

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lineno}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=red,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=red,
    linktocpage=true,
    }

\newcommand{\fromline}[1]{\linelabel{#1}\hypertarget{#1}{ }}
\newcommand{\toline}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{\lineref{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\fromline{bells} Olim, olim Deus accelere, hoc sæculum splendidum. Accelere fiat venire olim.

The first part of \textit{The Bells of Notre Dame} is in Latin, as found on line \toline{bells}.
\end{document}
```

It also doesn't make links in the table of contents, which is something I would like. Does anyone know why this might be? Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE is missing a `\linenumbers`. Once I added it, the line references worked as expected.